# How to make relationship tree for an entity (for example Pages) to show it on user interface?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have Pages table with the following fields: `id, title, parent_id`.
And I am going to build a tree of pages with the help of this.

I know that there is the special instruction in Postgresql like `WITH RECURSIVE`. It seems pretty close to my target.But I dont understand, how to use it.

I wrote something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
   SELECT id, parent_id, title
   FROM pages
   WHERE parent_id = 6

   UNION

   SELECT pages.id, pages.parent_id, pages.title
   FROM pages
      JOIN r
          ON pages.parent_id = r.id
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

But it's useless. It just shows me daughter elements for the page with id 6.

So, in user interface I would like to see something like this:

- Main page

  - News

    - Sport

      - Football
    - Politic

      - Russia

How I can walk the tree with the help of one request? Or there are another variants where I can make the same on the PHP side?

Comment: Are you sure page id #6 has grand children? Can you share some data? Also, what if you start with `id = 6` instead of `parent_id = 6`?

Comment: `parent_id = 6` is not important here. I need whole tree. From root to any leaves.

Comment: Then can you post a sample of records that should give you more than 1 level of recursion as well as the result you get?